# How do I read this drawing?

Tags: drawing

This is from the mechanical drawing for the XSON6 package in [this datasheet](http://ics.nxp.com/products/aup/datasheet/74aup1g157.pdf) (page 13).

[image]

What do the gray rectangles represent? Note that they don't have any measurements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See note 2: Can be visible in some manufacturing processes.

My guess is that there may be some exposed copper in this area.

Answer (score 2):

They will be the trimmed off extension of the internal contacts which extend out of the plastic at this point on the leaded versions. Plastic not thick enough it appears :-).

Comment: "Plastic not thick enough". That's what happens when every hundredth of a mm counts, I guess. Thanks for answering.